# Hamming Distance comparison with powershell

Tags: powershell

How can i compare 8 bit with another 8 bit to have something like this:

```
first Nr     1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
second Nr    1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
Result       r r f r r f r f

r = right 
f = false
```

Thanks

Comment: `$Result = -bNot $First -xor $Second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An annotated solution:

```
$firstNrBin  = '1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1'
$secondNrBin = '1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0'

# Convert the binary number strings to [byte]s (unsigned 8-bit values).
$firstNr = [Convert]::ToByte($firstNrBin -replace ' ', 2)   # 141 == 0x8d
$secondNr = [Convert]::ToByte($secondNrBin -replace ' ', 2) # 168 == 0xa8

# Perform bitwise XOR logic and negate the result to get a bit field
# that reflects the bits where the input numbers match.
# Note the need use of -band 0xff to limit the result to 8 bits - see
# explanation below.
# -> 218 == 0xda = 11011010
$bitsInCommon = [byte] (-bnot ($firstNr -bxor $secondNr) -band 0xff)

# Convert the bit field back into a binary representation, 0-padded to 8 chars.
# -> '11011010'
$bitsInComminBin = [Convert]::ToString($bitsInCommon, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')

# Produce the desired output format with string manipulation
$result = ([char[]] $bitsInComminBin -replace '1', 'r' -replace '0', 'f') -join ' '

# Output the result
[ordered] @{
  'first Nr' = $firstNrBin
  'second Nr' = $secondNrBin
  'Result' = $result
}
```

The above yields:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
first Nr                       1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
second Nr                      1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
Result                         r r f r r f r f
```

---

Note that **PowerShell's bitwise operators output `[int]` - `System.Int32` as the smallest data type, i.e., *signed* numbers**.

Therefore you have to mask out extra bits explicitly with the `-band` operator, because directly casting back to an *unsigned* type doesn't work.

In the case at hand:

```
$firstNr -bxor $secondNr # 141 -bxor 168
```

produces `37` as an `[int]` value, i.e, the following 32 bits:

```
00000000000000000000000000100101
```

Applying `-bnot` to this `[int]` yields the bitwise complement:

```
11111111111111111111111111011010
```

As an `[int]`, this is a *negative* number, because the high bit is set: `-38`

You cannot cast this directly back to an unsigned type such as `[byte]` to only get the lowest 8 bits, but you can use `-band` with bit mask `0xff` to zero out all bits beyond the first 8 ones - but note that the result is still an `[int]` at that point:

```
-bnot -38 -band 0xff
```

yields the following bits:

```
00000000000000000000000000100101
```

As an `[int]`, this is `37`, which you can safely cast back to `[byte]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bitwise comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comparison-operators):

e.g.

```
[byte]$a = 9       #00001001
[byte]$b = 12      #00001100

-bnot ($a -bxor $b) #11111010

$a -band $b        #00001000
$a -bor $b         #00001101
```

For your scenario you're looking at `-bxor` functionality, only taking the negative (`-bnot`) of the result.

---

If you need to see the flags themselves, you can use methods such as these:

```
function Format-BooleanString {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [byte]$ByteToDisplay 
    )
    Process {
        [string]$result = ''
        for ([int]$i = 7; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
            [int]$x = [Math]::Pow(2, $i)
            if ($ByteToDisplay -band $x) {
                $result += '1'
            } else {
                $result += '0'
            }
        }
        $result
    }
}
function Convert-BooleanStringToByte {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$ByteAsString
    )
    Process {
        if ($ByteAsString -notmatch '^[01]{8}$') {
            throw 'Input string must be 8 chars, consisting of only 0s and/or 1s'
        }
        [int]$result = 0
        for ([int]$i = 0; $i -lt 8; $i++) {
            if ($ByteAsString[$i] -eq '1') {
                $result += [Math]::Pow(2, 7-$i)
            }
        }
        [byte]$result            
    }

}

Format-BooleanString -ByteToDisplay 9
Convert-BooleanStringToByte -ByteAsString '00100010'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question.
But is there any possibility to do the bits and not numbers.
Regards

Comment: Sure... Under the covers they're the same thing; i.e. a number's just a collection of bits.  So it's only at display or input time that this makes a difference...  I've added a couple of functions which allow you to convert from/to the display values (I've used 1s and 0s, but you could easily amend it to work with `r`s and `f`s.

Comment: PERFECT.
Thanks a loot.

Comment: Helpful, but note that `-bnot ($a -bxor $b)` doesn't yield `11111010` (`250`), it yields `11111111111111111111111111111010` (`-6`), because the smallest data type that PowerShell's binary operators return is `[int]`, so you need to mask out the higher bits.
No real need for custom functions, because .NET supports these conversions directly: `$bin = [Convert]::ToString(9, 2)` and `[Convert]::ToByte($bin, 2)`

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, I wasn't aware of the second (base) parameter for those functions. Nice one.